# Как можно реализовать вывод свободного для записи времени на php?

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.

Есть автомойка и есть ее сайт, где можно записать на свободное время.
Автомойка работает с 8 до 20 часов. Может принимать клиентов каждые 30 минут. Т.е список времени для записи таков: 8:00, 8:30, 9:00, 9:30....и т.д.

Так же есть два вида услуг. Обычная мойка - занимает 30 минут времени и комплексная, рассчитанная на 1 час.

Данные о записи хранятся в базе таким образом: id, phone, date (это дата `d-m-Y`) и time (время `H:i`).
Вот нужно показывать посетителю свободное для записи время.

Это я сделал, но вопрос в нюансе, внимание:

Каким образом сформировать список времени в такой ситуации, когда 16:00, 16:30 - занято. 17:00 - свободно, 17:30 занято. Следовательно, человек не может записаться на комплексную мойку на **17:00**, потому что для нее нужен час.

**Как определить в таком случае что 17:00 не доступно?**

*Да и на сайте, прежде чем выводить время доступен выбор мойки: обычная или комплексная. После этого выбора должен формироваться список доступного времени.*

Comment: например, когда получаете из БД свободное время, дополнительно получайте время следующего события в той же строке. И на сайте тогда будете точно знать хватает вам времени или нет

Comment: Если вид мойки уже известен, то просто проверить, есть ли два свободных времени подряд.

Comment: Мне нужно выдать клиенту готовый список доступного времени для типа мойки, который он выбрал. Т.е  не так что бы ему выскочило сообщение о недоступности времени, а сразу формировать такой список, где нет недоступного времени

Comment: Мы поняли. Логику решения вам уже подсказали.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего задачу можно было бы решить, если бы выводились все возможные даты, но те, которые заняты, были бы не доступны для выбора. И в зависимости от выбора вида мойки нужно пользователю выбрать два или один интервал. Такая задача решается на Js.
Если у вас просто список `select`, в котором отображаются только доступные даты, то можно фильтровать их так:

```
<?php

$timeList = ['15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:30'];
$typeWashing = 2; // комплексная мойка, требует час

if ($typeWashing == 2) {
    $allowList = array();
    for (
        reset($timeList), $prevTime = null;
        ($currentTime = current($timeList));
        next($timeList), $prevTime = $currentTime
    ) {
        if ($prevTime === null) continue;

        // алгоритм проверяет предположение, что предыдущий интервал идёт сразу перед текущим
        // значит между ними есть 1 час, который требуется на комплексную мойку.
        $prevSplitTime = explode(':', $prevTime);
        $prevHour = $prevSplitTime[0];
        $prevMin = $prevSplitTime[1];

        $expectedHour = (string) (($prevMin == '00')? $prevHour : $prevHour + 1);
        $expectedMin = (string) (($prevMin == '00')? '30' : '00');
        $expectedTime = "{$expectedHour}:{$expectedMin}";

        if ($currentTime === $expectedTime) {
            $allowList[] = $prevTime;
        }
    }
} else {
    $allowList = $timeList;
}
```